# How to change bullet direction with respect to player direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I've been reading this question for a long time and some of the things they suggest I have them implemented in my code. But I cant still figure it out why is not working properly. If my player is facing right it shoots to the right but if its facing to the left it shoots to the right. My game is in 2D and I have my bullet prefab attach with this script, Im programming in C#.

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {


    public float speed;
    public float VelXBala;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (VelXBala,0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    void Update(){
        transform.Translate (1, 0, speed);
    }


    void OnBecameInvisible(){
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}
```

And I have my player script

```
public float speed;
    public Vector2 maxVel;
    public float airSpeed;
    public float jumpSpeed;
    public bool grounded;
    public Transform groundedEnd;
    public float jumpPower = 1;

    public GameObject bulletPrefab;


    private PlayerController controller;
    private Animator animator;


    void Start () {
        controller = GetComponent<PlayerController> ();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        maxVel = new Vector2 (3, 5);
        speed = 3f;
        airSpeed = 0.3f;
        jumpSpeed = 300f;
        grounded = false;
    }


    void Movement(){
        Vector2 force = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
        Vector2 absVelocity = new Vector2 (rigidbody2D.velocity.x, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
        Vector2 currentPosition = new Vector2(rigidbody2D.position.x, rigidbody2D.position.y);

        if (controller.moving.x != 0) {
            if (absVelocity.x < maxVel.x){
                force.x = grounded ? (speed * controller.moving.x) :
                    (speed * airSpeed * controller.moving.x);
                transform.localScale = new Vector2 (controller.moving.x, 1);
            }
            animator.SetInteger ("AnimState", 1);
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(speed*Time.deltaTime*controller.moving.x, 0));
        } else {
            animator.SetInteger("AnimState", 0);
        }

        /*if (controller.moving.y > 0 && grounded) {
            force.y = jumpSpeed;
            rigidbody2D.AddForce(force);
            //animator.SetInteger("AnimState", 2);
        }*/

        if(!grounded && rigidbody2D.velocity.y == 0) {
            grounded = true;
        }
        if (controller.moving.y>0 && grounded == true) {
            rigidbody2D.AddForce(transform.up*jumpPower);
            grounded = false;
            animator.SetInteger("AnimState",2);
        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            //crea un clon de un objeto
            Instantiate(bulletPrefab,transform.position,transform.rotation);

        }

    }





    void Update () {
        Movement ();

    }


}
```

Comment: In your bullet script you are translating your GameObject in direction 1, 0, speed... Translate's parameters are x,y,z so you are sending your bullet right (1) everytime.

Comment: Note that you really shouldn't need to call `Translate()` at all. If you initialize the bullet properly, setting its velocity (to the correct direction, of course), then the engine should handle the rest for you.

Comment: Also please note that you can use Debug.DrawLine() in Update or FixedUpdate to help you figure this stuff out. It's been an indispensable tool for me. (It shows up in the scene view, not the game view.)

Answer (score 0):

You are updating bullet position by translating it (1, 0, 0), so it will always moving to the right.

Supposing you are instantiating the bullet in the right position and orientation:

```
Instantiate(bulletPrefab,transform.position,transform.rotation);
```

You must update your bullet position to move forward:

```
void Update(){
    transform.position += Vector3.forward * speed;
}
```